# PDO->exec handling delimiters

Tags: php, mysql, percona

I've ran into some curious behaviour of exec. Exec somehow does not care about wrong usage of delimters in the sql of a function.

```
"CREATE FUNCTION `parse_groups_path`(subpath BLOB) RETURNS text CHARSET latin1 DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
        DECLARE i INT UNSIGNED;
        DECLARE id INT UNSIGNED;
       [..]
```

Here the default delimiter ; is in use. When running this against a MYSQL database through either:
`mysql < file.sql` or `mysql -e "sql code"` this fails with:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3
```

However running the same file against the DB using PDO:

```
$db->exec(file_get_contents($file));
```

or

```
$db->exec($sql);
```

This error does not appear.

Correcting the function script by setting `DELIMITER //` fixes it

Running:

Percona MYSQL version 5.7.26-29, as:
`mysqld --sql-mode='' --init-connect='SET SESSION time_zone="cet";SET NAMES "utf8";SET AUTOCOMMIT=1;'`

PHP version 7.2.24

Does anyone know why PDO->exec does not throw an error, while running the SQL does?

**UPDATE**

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=revolution", "root", "");
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$file = "fubar.sql";
$db->exec(file_get_contents($file));
```

Also works just fine.

Comment: *"Anyone know why this happens?"*  The why is explained [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html)

Comment: That does not explain why PDO->exec() seems to disregard this error. Ill update the question.

Comment: Fair enough it was meant as explained why the error happend.. check the source code then why reading it as file does not trigger the error without using a delimiter..

Comment: Ye, I read through the exec source code, but the main function doesn't do anything weird. So figured I would ask here before diving in deep.

Comment: Are you running PDO in cliënt side prepare emulation mode instead of serverside mode...That might explain it..

Comment: I am not setting any attributes. Simply just opening a connection.

Tried:

`$db = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=revolution", "root", "");`

`$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true);`

`$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

`$file = "fubar.sql";`

`$db->exec(file_get_contents($file));`

Remains quiet and works.

Comment: `ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` should be `false` defined **always** to do server side prepares, much better for security plus you need to define a charset in the connection string as client side prepare emulation can lead into SQl injections much more easy  especially if you didn't define a charset to use on your connection as (multibyte) charset encoding injections could also lead to SQL injections even with prepared statements..  Anyhow consider stop using `ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES true` from now on ..

Comment: This is just a test setup against a local container, trying to provoke `PDO->exec()` to actually throw an error. Not reflective of a production connection, but appreciate the headsup regardless.